# How to periodically request data from golang and use them in html page

Tags: javascript, html, go

I'm very new to golang and to web development in general.

I would like to update only a section of my html page periodically (say 300 ms).
The section that needs to be updated is an image drawn into a canvas.
I'd like to retrieve the img.src path from the golang server.

My javascript code is the following:

```js
<script type="text/JavaScript">

  var refreshInterval = 300; // ms
  var img;
  
  function init() {
      var context = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
      img = new Image();
      img.onload = function() {
          context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
      };
      refresh();
  }

  function refresh()
  {
      img.src = "image.jpeg" // This is the path I'd like to get from golang
      setTimeout("refresh()",refreshInterval);
  }
  </script>
```

I already tried using golang templates, but in that case the complete page is reloaded and that's not what I want.

I also have some controls in the web page (textfield, spinbox, etc..) and if the page is reloaded I lose the focus on the control I'm using.

**UPDATE**

I solved my problem using AJAX. I removed the canvas and used a standard img element.

Thank you for pinpointing me to the correct direction.

I leave the code here in case someone will need it:

```js
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script>
      var refreshInterval = 300; // ms

      $(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(updateImage, refreshInterval);
      });

      function updateImage()
      {
        $.ajax({ url: 'get-image',
                 type: 'get',
                 dataType: 'text',
                 success : function(data) {
                   $('#myImage').attr('src', data);
                 },
                });
        setTimeout(updateImage, refreshInterval);
      }
    </script>
```

```html
<img id="myImage"/>
```

Comment: You need a web service in golang that returns only the image path. The web service response therefore has `Content-Type: text/plain`. (Also, `setTimeout(refresh, refreshInterval)` is the correct usage.)

Comment: Change setTimeout("refresh()",refreshInterval) to setTimeout("refresh",refreshInterval).

Comment: Use ajax query to change img.src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX